# Check if username already exists SQL react

Tags: sql, reactjs, validation, axios

I setting up some validation for a register form I've created. The validation for checking if a username already exists seems to work however my else statement is triggered. Meaning even if they enter a username that's already in my table they will receive an error message but it will be added to the table anyway.

Heres the code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function Register() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

    const inputs = [
        {
            placeholder: 'First name',
            setState: setFirstName
        },
        {
            placeholder: 'Last name',
            setState: setLastName
        },
        {
            placeholder: 'Email',
            setState: setEmail
        },
        {
            placeholder: 'Enter a username',
            setState: setUsername
        },
        {
            placeholder: 'Enter a password',
            setState: setPassword,
        },

        {
            placeholder: 'Confirm password',
            setState: setConfirmPassword,
        },
    ]

    //Insert into database api request
    const insertRow = () => {
        axios.post('/users/insert', {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
        });
    };

    //#region Validation
        const atSymbol = '@';

        //Checks for numbers in string
        function containsNumber(str) {
            return /[0-9]/.test(str);
        }

        //Checks for capital in string
        function containsCapital(str) {
            return /[A-Z]/.test(str);
        }

        //Redirects to login page
        const submitHandler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); //Prevents page refresh

            //If no @ symobol in email
            if (!email.includes(atSymbol)) {
                alert('Please enter a valid email address');
            }

            //If username already exists
            if (username) {
               axios.get('/users/get')
                .then(res => {
                    res.data.forEach(row => {
                        if (row.username === username) {
                            alert('Username already exists');
                        }
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }

            //If password doesn't contain a capital
            if (!containsCapital(password)) {
                alert('Password must contain at least one uppercase letter');
            }

            //If password doesn't contain a number
            if (!containsNumber(password)) {
                alert('Password must contain at least one number');
            }

            //If password is less than 8 characters
            if (password.length < 8) {
                alert('Password must be at least 8 characters long');
            }

            //If passwords don't match
            if (confirmPassword !== password) {
                alert('Passwords do not match');
            }

            //If all validation passes
            else {
                insertRow();
                
                navigate('/login');
            }
        }
    //#endregion

    return (
        <>
        <Helmet>
            <title>Title | Register</title>
        </Helmet>

            <div className="pt-36 sm:pt-44 pb-20 md:pb-48 max-w-[1200px] mx-5 lg:mx-auto">
                <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="flex flex-col space-y-5 max-w-[500px] mx-auto">
                    {inputs.map((items, index) => (
                        <input 
                            key={index}
                            type="text" 
                            className="border-2 border-black p-1"
                            placeholder={`${items.placeholder} *`} 
                            required 
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                items.setState(e.target.value);
                            }}
                        />
                    ))}

                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        sx={{
                                border: '2px solid #000000',
                                color: '#000000',
                                marginLeft: 'auto',
                                marginRight: 'auto',

                                ':hover': {
                                    bgcolor: '#ffffff',
                                    color: '#000000',
                                },
                            }}
                    >
                    Submit
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: The only `else` statement in the code is related to the condition `if (confirmPassword !== password)` which doesn't have anything to do with a username existing in a database.  It's not clear to me what you're asking or what problem you're describing.  When you debug your code, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

You will always add a user to the table if confirmPassword === password. The rest of the if constructs are not related to the last else. Solution:
In each if, after the error message, write return and remove the else construct. If at least some if block works, then the function will no longer be executed due to return

```js
 if (!containsCapital(password)) {
      alert('Password must contain at least one uppercase letter');
      return;
  }

  //If password doesn't contain a number
  if (!containsNumber(password)) {
      alert('Password must contain at least one number');
      return;
  }

  //If password is less than 8 characters
  if (password.length < 8) {
      alert('Password must be at least 8 characters long');
      return;
  }

  //If passwords don't match
  if (confirmPassword !== password) {
      alert('Passwords do not match');
      return;
  }

  //If all validation passes
  insertRow();
  navigate('/login');
```

Comment: Still have the same issue of inserting despite triggering error